# How to prevent different checksums for different typesets

Tags: pdf

If I consider a simple LaTeX document such as:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\begin{document}
Hello, World!
\end{document}
```

then if I typeset it multiple times I get a different checksum each time

```
$ pdflatex test
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-1.40.10 (TeX Live 2009)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
...
Output written on test.pdf (1 page, 12592 bytes).
Transcript written on test.log.
$ cksum test.pdf
2770399004 12592 test.pdf
$ pdflatex test
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-1.40.10 (TeX Live 2009)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
...
Output written on test.pdf (1 page, 12592 bytes).
Transcript written on test.log.
$ cksum test.pdf
1225641903 12592 test.pdf
```

The different checksum is due to three lines changing in the PDF file:

```
/CreationDate (D:20101115092454-05'00')
/ModDate (D:20101115092454-05'00')
...
/ID [<E52BBC1CEFDC95455342C233D35D790A> <E52BBC1CEFDC95455342C233D35D790A>] >>
```

This is also the case with more complicated LaTeX input. Is there a way to typeset LaTeX files that would avoid this issue, so that if typeset multiple times, the checksum of the PDF file stays the same?

Comment: Could you do a checksum of the source instead?

Comment: It looks like you will have to suppress the embedding of the Creation Date and Modification Date into the PDF.  Are you sure you want to do that?

Comment: @Matthew: I have had the same problem several times (not only with Latex but also with many other tools that generate PDF files). Is there a very good reason to have those two timestamps embedded in the PDF file? Do the PDF standards require them? Is there a PDF viewer that actually uses those fields for something useful?

Comment: @Jukka: I believe search engines look at file metadata so it's good for that to be in there.  But maybe there's a package/pdflatex patch that will avoid it.

Comment: Oh, it seems that this was answered at superuser.com: http://superuser.com/questions/130347/how-do-i-produce-bytewise-consistent-documents-with-pdflatex

Comment: I've had the same problem when diffing DVI or PS files. There also the time stamp changes.

Comment: @Will, wouldn't it depend on the purpose for the checksum, e.g., if (artefact+checksum) were to be distributed sans source. Still, I guess it's academic now Yossi's sussed a useful answer from the interwebs.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think that it is worth repeating the answer here. (Since this a is an exact copy from [superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/130347/how-do-i-produce-bytewise-consistent-documents-with-pdflatex), I should not get any rep for it...so I'm marking it CW):

> You can change the contents of the pdf's Info dictionary using pdftex's `\pdfinfo` macro:
>
> ```
> \def\fixedpdfdate{D:20100413000000+00’00’}
> \pdfinfo{
>     /CreationDate (\fixedpdfdate)
>     /ModDate (\fixedpdfdate) }
> ```
>
> Put this right at the beginning of the document: there's some risk that the dictionary gets written out in several chunks.

Comment: Just to note that, `\pdfinfo` is not a macro but rather a primitive that is only available in pdftex and derived engines (i.e. luatex, but not xetex).

Comment: Thanks! Any idea how to prevent the same from happening with the \ID line at the bottom of the PDF files?

Comment: @astrofrog: I thought that `/ID` was a checksum: obviously not.  It looks like PDF readers don't mind you mutating the value of this object, so that the PDF between `/ID` and `startxref` reads: `/ID [<0> <0>] >> startxref` - I'd be interested to hear if any PDF readers are bothered about this.  It may be the case that there is a cleaner way to nail down this value, though I'm guessing that Pdftex doesn't give you control over this.

Comment: For luatex the primitive has to be activated before it can be used: `\protected\def\pdfinfo  {\pdfextension info }`

Answer (score 0):

## **SOURCE_DATE_EPOCH**

### TL;DR

Create a file called Makefile with these contents and then type `make`.

```
all: test.pdf
%.pdf: %.tex
	SOURCE_DATE_EPOCH=`(git log -1 --format=%at $< 2>/dev/null; \
	                    date +%s -r $<) | head -1` \
	pdflatex $<
```

You do not need to understand this to use it.

---

### Explanation for the curious

While the accepted answer is good, there is another solution that does not require modifying the .tex file, works with any modern TeX engine (pdfTeX, LuaTeX, XeTeX), and can update when the .tex file changes. The core idea is to set the environment variable **SOURCE_DATE_EPOCH**, a variable used for [reproducible builds](https://reproducible-builds.org/specs/source-date-epoch/).

### Fixed Date Example

First, here's an example which is similar to the accepted answer in that it hardcodes a specific date, formatted as seconds since the [epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) (à la  `date +%s`).

```bash
$ export SOURCE_DATE_EPOCH=1694000000
$ pdflatex test.tex && md5sum test.pdf
badef9728436749defaec3982f86e4e0  test.pdf
$ pdflatex test.tex && md5sum test.pdf
badef9728436749defaec3982f86e4e0  test.pdf
$ pdfinfo test.pdf | grep Mod
ModDate:         Wed Sep  6 11:33:20 2023 UTC
```

That works, but read on for a better way.

### Using the latex file's modification time

Depending upon whether you store your latex files in a git repository or not, you can use one of these to retrieve the modification time:

- **With git**: `git log -1 --format=%at test.tex`
- **Without git**: `date +%s -r test.tex`

For example,

```bash
SOURCE_DATE_EPOCH=`git log -1 --format=%at test.tex` pdflatex test.tex
```

### Putting it all together

The above commands can be wrapped in a shell script or [Makefile](https://makefiletutorial.com/). Here is an example of the latter which uses git, if available, and falls back to the file modification timestamp:

```
all: test.pdf

# Pattern rule for building a pdf from any latex source file.
# Note: $< represents the .tex filename.
%.pdf: %.tex FORCE
	SOURCE_DATE_EPOCH=`(git log -1 --format=%at $< 2>/dev/null; \
	                    date +%s -r $<) | head -1` \
	pdflatex $<

FORCE:
```

To use it, just type `make` to create test.pdf. Or, since it uses a pattern rule, you could type `make foo.pdf` and it would look for a file named foo.tex.

Note: the `FORCE` target is optional. It lets you run `make` repeatedly to re-run pdflatex, as necessary, for cross-references and bibliography.