# Can I get exactly the same pdf document (sha1) when I recompile latex document?

Tags: xetex, pdf

If there are no date/time specific variables in tex content (just text)...
Can I after running `xelatex` command get the same .pdf (byte to byte) when .tex file isn't changed?

Comment: Did you read [How to prevent different checksums for different typesets](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5401/14500)?

Comment: The `/ID` in the PDF trailer is always modified.