Automatic check that two source LaTeX files produce the same symbols?
There is an existing question here whether it is possible to check that two source LaTeX files produce the same pdf.
I am looking for something less strict: I don't need to know that the pdfs will be pixel-for-pixel the same, I just want to automatically check that two LaTeX source files produce the same text and mathematical symbols. It's ok if there are formatting differences. It is not ok to e.g. replace $\int_a$ by $\int_\alpha$.
How would one do this?

For text you can extract the text of the PDFs to compare them. But IMHO this won't work for math. You could also use StrongBad's answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/403381/277964, but ignore some of the box information (but not all, because position can change the meaning). But if different fonts are allowed, you always would need visual comparison, because someone could use a manipulated font, that prints, e.g., “a” instead of alpha (or even more extreme changes). Maybe you could train a KI to compare the PDFs. But this would be off-topic here.

@cabohah, to be clear I don't need this to be robust to malign adversaries. I just need it check that after a well-meaning user makes formatting changes, we don't accidentally change the content.

A well-meaning user can also accidentally use a broken (or manipulated) font.

@cabohah, good point. (though if the method couldn't deal with that specifically, it'd still be better than nothing).

There are a lot of changes, for which it is not a-priory clear, whether they are allowed or not. For example moving some text, e.g., can improve the clarity and therefore can be allowed, but it also changes the text and therefore can be forbidden. Changing “Figure 1” in “figure 1” can be allowed or not. Correcting a typing mistake can (and usually should) be allowed, but also is a text change. Changing paragraph or page breaking can be allowed, because they improve the typography, or not, because they change the text. So you first need to specify, which changes are allowed and which are not.

Usually, the more you go into detail, the more difficult it becomes to answer what should and should not be allowed. And each decision can either make the comparison of documents (or their sources) more difficult or easier. Most easiest would indeed be a pixel comparison (no visual changes allowed) or the comparison of extracted text (with need to handle math separately, maybe pixel by pixel or source sync). And these are IMHO also the two extremes of automatic comparability.

@cabohah, "For example moving some text", no this would be a change in the content and the program should mark it as a change. typo corrections also are not "allowed". I mean more accurately, the program I'm looking for should flag them, they can still be accepted.

Ideally I'd want to do some kind of diff check on extracted "plaintext" but where math symbols are also extracted losslessly.

l3build provides methods to normalise output to determine whether the result of typesetting a test file has changed as a result of changes to the software. the general idea is that you produce textual output (or pdf, but usually text) which l3build then normalises to reduce failures due to irrelevant differences. so you produce this output once and then compare the result when subsequently testing.

but it isn't obvious to me why you don't compare the source rather than the result of typesetting. why not diff the .tex files, for example?

@cfr, the source files might replace $x$ by $\myx$ with \newcommand{\myx}{x}, or any number of other changes which shouldnt be flagged as changes

Tools like pdf2txt also convert math with a best-effort approach, something like \cB_{S \cup \{k\},k+1} is converted (from the pdf output) into cBS∪{k},k+1, which is not really readable but it is reproducible/faithful to the original - so it might be used for comparisons.
