# Check whether or not a file is the source of a compiled document

Tags: compiling

If I have a document compiled from a LaTeX source file, is it possible to check wether that document was compiled from a certain source file? I.e. do DVI or PDF files store anything identifying about the source file it was compiled from?

Comment: no you would have to compile your test source and compare with the dvi or pdf you have

Comment: You can use the package [attachfile2](https://ctan.org/pkg/attachfile2) for attaching the LaTeX source files to the .pdf-file. Then you can use [PDFtk](https://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/) or the like software for extracting the LaTeX source files from the .pdf-file. Probably this makes checking whether or not a file is the source of a compiled document obsolete. Besides this: The same LaTeX sources might yield different results when compiled on different TeX platforms. Content created by random-generator or commands like `\today` might complicate the check.

Comment: Some approaches following David's comment can be found on https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/403369/check-that-two-tex-sources-generate-the-same-pdf. Also related https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/403369/check-that-two-tex-sources-generate-the-same-pdf and https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5401/how-to-prevent-different-checksums-for-different-typesets, although those two are specific to pdfTeX.